# AVFoundationつかって動画にロゴを付加したい

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

swiftで動画編集アプリを作成しています。

AVFoundationを使って動画にロゴを追加する機能を作成しています。

objective-cのサンプルはいくつか見つけることができたのですが
swiftでのサンプルがなかなかありません。
＋objective-cのサンプルをswiftに書き換えて試してみてはいるもののうまくいきません。

どなたかいいサンプルなどありましたら教えていただきたいです。。。

当方、ios開発始めてから1ヶ月も経ってない根っからの初心者です。

Answer (score 1):

これでいけました（Ob-Cですが。。。）

```
    - (void)setLogo:(AVMutableVideoComposition *)videoComposition
{
    UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermark"];
    CALayer *logoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    logoLayer.contents = (id)logo.CGImage;
    logoLayer.frame = CGRectMake( 15, height - 83, 67, 68);
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height );
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height );
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:logoLayer];
    videoComposition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer
                                                                                                                                  inLayer:parentLayer];
}
```